# sql server, procedures and function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a Studentstatus table which gets a list of students from student table.

I made this procedure to update or create a new record, but I get the following error:

> Procedure or function SaveAdvStudStata has too many arguments specified.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveAdvStudStata]
@studentId int,
@stata int,
@description varchar(MAX),
@date DATE,
@issuedBy nvarchar(128)

AS 
BEGIN
if exists (select StudentId
           from dbo.StudentStata
           where StudentId = @studentId
          )
        begin
            Update dbo.StudentStata
            set Stata = @stata
               ,Description = @description
               ,Date = @date
               ,IssuedBy = @issuedBy
            where StudentId = @studentId
        end
    else
        begin
            Insert into dbo.StudentStata(StudentId
                                        ,Stata
                                        ,Description
                                        ,Date
                                        ,IssuedBy
                                        )
            VALUES (@studentId
                   ,@stata
                   ,@description
                   ,@date
                   ,@issuedBy
                   )
        end
END
```

Comment: Do you get that error when you try to use the function?  Can you post the script where you are trying to use it, it looks like you are not providing the right amount of parameters.

Comment: This usually means you try to execute the stored procedure (or udf) with the wrong amount of parameters. check the execute code.